# How to understand a downvote

Tags: support, feature-request, downvoting

Is there any way to understand who or at least why a downvote was awarded?

Because in 2 cases that I got a downvote, the answer seemed perfectly fine and also had upvotes from other users.

The only thing being that they were simpler ways to go around the stuff instead of a sophisticated way from the terminal.

How can users just downvote because they personally felt the answer to be "less technical for a Linux user" (that's the only reason I can see in those downvotes) or just because their answers to the same question should be considered?

Users just downvote without giving a reason!

This is just not acceptable!

There needs to be some way to find this out!

If this feature is not yet into use I would like to suggest it!

Comment: Could you please include links to the referred answer?

Comment: Again a downvote here??
Now hat is wrong in the question??
Could the downvoter explain why?

Comment: YES-in the 1st link,there was as upvote at first and then a downvote by someone else http://askubuntu.com/questions/138026/how-do-i-delete-kernels-from-a-server/138038#138038...and in the second link,i have given a link to an answer which i had answer and had the problem solved.Its a link to an ACCEPTED answer. Then why the downvote?

Comment: meta downvotes == I don't agee.

Comment: Downvote without comment → ignore. It's *that* easy! :-)

Comment: The problem is with loosing reputation..!! :)

Comment: Duplicates - http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3047/who-downvoted-my-question-answer-on-ask-ubuntu http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2008/down-voting-consequences

Comment: Please don't use so many exclamation marks in your question--it appears rude to others as if you were screaming at them.

Comment: "Do not assume that anyone owes you an explanation for their down vote. They do not. While people are encouraged to explain when they down vote, they are not at all required to do so." from http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121350/ive-just-been-down-voted-how-should-i-react-to-this

Comment: @Nirmik, I totally agree with your view point. It seems that StackExchange needs a complete policy re-design.

Answer (score 8):

Downvotes are a means to tell the OP that his post is neither useful to the community in specific nor to the Internet in general. If you scroll your mouse over the downvote option you can see the overlay text *This answer is not useful*. That should already give you a rough idea on why your answer was downvoted.

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/138038/25798) is clearly incorrect because the OP already mentions that GUI-methods don't really work for him. In that case, it just shows that you didn't spend enough time to thoroughly read the question and understand what it requires in your answer.

The other answer (which seems to be deleted now) is not useful either because you are just linking to another answer. Worse still, the linked answer of yours is suggesting to use Google Chrome to solve the OP's problem of not being able to watch Flash videos in Opera.

We have guidelines on how to proceed with such answers. Give it a read when you have some time:

- http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2378/how-should-answers-which-basically-equate-to-give-up-and-use-x-instead-be-hand

If you don't know a better way to solve an OP's problem, it is better not to answer at all than to misguide them incorrectly.

In case you are ever downvoted again, go through this question and see how best you can react to the downvote.

- [I've just been downvoted. How should I react to this?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121350/ive-just-been-down-voted-how-should-i-react-to-this)

---

On a side note, you can read about how voting is different on Meta.

- [Why are people downvoting my questions on meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42558/why-are-people-downvoting-my-question-on-meta)

Comment: ahem ahem! i dont understand how you got 4 upboats on that. I'm resisting myself not to downvote. read the first line of your answer aloud. thrice.

Comment: Mahesh, I wondered if he would fix it, but I decided to fix it myself rather than complain :-)

Comment: I would've gladly fixed it myself, if only i found the 'edit' link. btw, what rep is required to be able to edit on meta?

Comment: @Mahesh 2k. Just like on the main site. Anyway, thanks both of you for fixing the broken answer.

Answer (score 5):

Looking at your answers that have been downvoted, in this case : [How do I delete kernels from a server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138026/how-do-i-delete-kernels-from-a-server/138038#138038) The question stated that the OP was unable to use GUI methods to solve the problem, and your answer involved installing Ubuntu Tweak which they wouldn't be able to do.

In this answer: [Can't watch Youtube Flash videos in Opera Browser on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138003/cant-watch-youtube-flash-videos-in-opera-browser-on-ubuntu/138004#138004) your answer was a link to another of your answer which stated to install Chrome, it isn't desirable to just leave a link as an answer, and installing a new browser isn't a good solution to the question.

That said it would be helpful if whoever had downvoted these had left a comment to explain their actions, this would help to explain what was wrong with the post and how it can be improved.

Comment: But then i have specified in thr second link to refer to the discussion below which is about the alternatives to flash player for other browsers line gnash.!!

Comment: And also in the 1st link the user has specified about not being able to use Synaptic.The user has not stated that his GUI is not working at all!! Then how can we not consider giving him an alternate GUI solution to the GUI tool he says is not working?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any way to understand who or at least why a downvote was awarded?

No, not unless the person left a comment - which need not mean that that's the person who cast a downvote.

Answer #1:

- https://askubuntu.com/a/138004/1182

> Check the compete discussion on this answer: [No sound in Flash videos](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137024/no-sound-in-flash-videos/137030#137030)
>
> This will definitely solve it

This should be a comment, not an answer.

Answer #2:

- [How do I delete kernels from a server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138026/how-do-i-delete-kernels-from-a-server/138038#138038)

OP says

> I can't really use GUI

.. and yet your answer tells a GUI tool

> This is just not acceptable!

No, Voting is anonymous and you should be ready accept any vote - up or down.

> If this feature is not yet into use I would like to suggest it!

[This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93355/badge-to-encourage-leaving-comments-on-downvote-constructive-critic) [has](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32226/why-not-allow-downvote-only-with-at-least-an-anonymous-comment) [been](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110279/must-comment-while-downvoting) [discussed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6521/allow-users-to-leave-an-anonymous-comment-when-voting) [Ad nauseam](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=encourage%20comment%20on%20downvote) on [Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) and declined.

Comment: But in the link-http://askubuntu.com/questions/138026/how-do-i-delete-kernels-from-a-server/138038#138038 the user has specified about not being able to use Synaptic.The user has not stated that his GUI is not working at all!! Then how can we not consider giving him an alternate GUI solution to the GUI tool he says is not working?

Comment: `I can't really use GUI` --> did you not read that? As for alternate solutions, others seem to have done fine. @nirm

Comment: "I can't really use GUI-based methods like synaptic"--> did you read that?? there is no fullstop after GUI which means the statment doesnot end at GUI..!!

Comment: @Nirmik what has statement ending got to do? The OP has clearly mentioned he can't use GUI, it's up to you to comprehend that & post an answer. If you can't, drop a comment asking for clarification

Comment: Yeah i surely have done it to clarify...Lets see what the user has to say now.

Comment: plus its "server", just because he said "like synaptic" shouldn't lead you to believe the only GUI he could not use is synaptic.

Comment: Nirmik, even if you're correct and only certain GUI-based methods were being excluded, consider the amount of time you've spent on this.  You'll always get downvotes: it's part of the "noise" that exists in any voting system.  Spend the energy instead to contributing more quality answers and in the end that will increase your reputation much more than worrying about this will.