# How to know who voted you?

Tags: discussion

I was just wondering if there is any way to know who voted(up/down/favorite) on your question/answer.

just wanna know if possible.

Comment: Similar question - the answer is the same though - http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3047/who-downvoted-my-question-answer-on-ask-ubuntu

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image]

There's a few reasons for that - to prevent revenge/antirevenge voting for examples. To a limited extent mods will be informed of unusual voting patterns (though in most cases this is automated), but there's no way at all for a user to know, without a comment made by the voter of who voted on a specific question question.

Answer (score 6):

No there is no way to know. Not even moderators have access to that information.

See: [Is there a way to see who voted on your posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12984/is-there-a-way-to-see-who-voted-on-your-posts)